# Maximum Value of $a+b+c$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

> Given that  $a+\frac {11}b+\frac c4=20$, what is the maximum value of $a+b+c$? Here, $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

I tried to find the maximum from the AM-GM relationship but failed.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: This doesn't make sense at it stands. What is the condition on $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: With the edits made to the question, I'm voting to *reopen*, since the question is now clear. That said, it would be a great idea for OP to include some of their thoughts on this problem, in order to receive better answers and ensure the question is not closed for insufficient context.

Comment: Ok the problem makes sense now. I still think the question should be closed since there is a lack of context: what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. If this is added, then I agree with reopening.

Comment: I tried from AM GM relationship to get maximum value of a+b+c but fails.

Comment: Trial and error is pretty straightforward.  Speeds things up if you note that $\frac {11}b$ has got to be of the form $\frac n4$ (possibly not in lowest terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$b > 0 \implies \frac{11}{b} > 0
\implies a + \frac{c}{4} < 20 \iff 4a+c < 80 \implies 4a + c \le 79$$

This leads to

$$b = \frac{11}{20- \left(a + \frac{c}{4}\right)} = \frac{44}{80 - (4a + c)} \le \frac{44}{80-79} = 44$$

Furthermore, $a \ge 1$ implies

$$a + c \le 79 - 3a \le 79 - 3 = 76$$

Combine these, we can conclude $a + b + c \le 76 + 44 = 120$.

Since this value $120$ is achieved by $(a,b,c) = (1,44,75)$ and
$1 + \frac{11}{44} + \frac{75}{4} = 20$. The maximum value of $a + b + c$ equals to $120$.

Comment: Thank you nicely done

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a=1$ and $\frac{44}{b}=76-c$ implies $b|44$.